# How can I aggregate the data from two functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I try to aggregate my two MongoDB databases, but for now I fall into the problem with collecting the information from them.

So, what I try to do is to make an `object` from two databases. 
And my problem is that the functions `User.find()` and `EmployersSchemaDB.find()` does not push the variables/obj outside after aggregation. You can see it in the code below...

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD Based on answer in comments:**

```
router.route('/employers')
.get((req, res) => {
    function getDate() {
        console.log('Hi');
        let obj = {
            userCookies: '',
            EmployersObj: {}
        } 
        const userFind = User.find((err, users) => {
            if (err) { res.send(err) }
            if (req.session.userId !== undefined) {
                obj.userCookies = req.session.userId;
                return obj.userCookies;
            } else {
                obj.userCookies = '';
                return obj.userCookies;
            }
        });

        const employerFind = EmployersSchemaDB.find((err, employers) => {
            if (err) { res.send(err) }
                obj.EmployersObj = employers;
                return obj.EmployersObj;
        });

        Promise.all(userFind, employerFind).then(responseArr => { 
            return res.json(responseArr);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    getDate();
})
```

**Error Log:**

```
Server running on port 3016
19:23:24 Server.1   |  Hi
19:23:24 Server.1   |  TypeError: undefined is not a function
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at Function.all (<anonymous>)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at getDate (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\Server\server.js:194:21)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at router.route.get (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\Server\server.js:198:9)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at next (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at next (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at Function.handle (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at router (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at trim_prefix (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
19:23:24 Server.1   |      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\\Desktop\react\mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
ayer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: "You can see it in the log of my code below..." what log?

Comment: @Luca I mean the `console.logs` and my comments right of them

Comment: i've updated my answer, you can have a look & see if that works for you

Comment: oops. promise.all expect an array, so that's what was wrong. updated again

Answer (score 0):

Likely because your `EmployersSchemaDB.find()` method returns a promise. You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to execute both of your queries then handle their response once they complete:

```
router
  .route('/employers')
  .get((req, res) => {
    const userFind = User.find();
    const employerFind = EmployersSchemaDB.find();

    Promise.all([userFind, employerFind])
      .then(responseArr => {
        return res.json(formatResponse(responseArr, '' || req.session.userId));
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  })

function formatResponse(arr, cookies) {
  console.log('formatRes hi', arr);
  const obj = {
    userCookies: cookies,
    usersRes = arr[0],
    employersRes: arr[1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it work, but how we can create the full object on output builded on promises? I'm just not so good familiar with it...

Comment: Thank you for improvements, but now I get an error from your code - `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: Node 9+

I UPD my question with the Eror logs for You.

Comment: Again Error, sorry ( .... `TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined`

Comment: Error again - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined` (... I laso tring to build this case on async/await, but istead of returning the concrete value from MongoDB methods I always returns the whole arrray of data in it... It's something strange...

Comment: okay to have to firgure things out for yourself a bit. read the error. it says that it cannot read `userId` of `undefined`. what means that `res.session` does not exist. maybe it's a typo and it should be `req.session`